# Does javascript Array.slice(0) return a shallow copy?

Tags: javascript

IIUC `Array.slice(0)` returns a copy of the array.  Is it a shallow copy?  In other words the array items still have the same memory location, but the array container gets assigned a new one?

Effectively:

```
let oldArray = ['old', 'array'];
let newArray = oldarray.slice(0);
let same = oldArray[0] === newArray[0]; //true 
let same = oldArray === newArray; //false
```

Comment: Yes, if the items in the array are objects, they will not be coped, only referenced in a new array container. You have to go to *some significant effort* to actually deep copy arrays and objects in general (thankfully).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,see demo:

```js
var o = [{
  x: 1
}]
var o2 = o.slice(0)
o2[0].x = 2
console.log(o[0].x)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct - it does create a shallow copy.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

> The slice() method returns a **shallow copy** of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

If you are wanting a deep copy you can do the ye ole dirty dirt:

```js
var arr = [1]; 
var arr2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));

arr[0] = 99;
arr2[0] = 1000;

console.log({arr, arr2});
```